# Remove duplicates based on column but keep unique values from other column concatenated in new dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to remove duplicate rows based on a column from a Dataframe like this:

| ColumnA | ColumnB |
| --- | --- |
| John | 2 |
| Jorge | 2 |

I want to do it in a way i can keep the values from ColumnA in a new ColumnA as 'Jorge; John' when duplicates appear in ColumnB. I tried `df.drop_duplicates(subset='ColumnB', keep="last")` but i dont seem to figure out a way of keeping both names from the initial ColumnA, after removing duplicate.

I was expecting something like:

| ColumnA | ColumnB |
| --- | --- |
| John; Jorge | 2 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df_new = df.groupby('ColumnB', as_index=False)['ColumnA'].agg('; '.join)
```